# Can't see permissions for new model in Django's admin interface

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

I registered a new model in Django's admin interface but I can't see any permissions related to it that I can assign to users or groups.

Could it be related to the fact that my models come from a different database?

Comment: Can you post your `admin.py` and `models.py` for that model?

Comment: Maybe run `./manage.py syncdb --all`?

Comment: `admin.py` is just `admin.site.register(Product)` and the model doesn't have anything special.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a very similar issue today where I couldn't assign Users permissions concerning tables that were created in multiple databases because those tables didn't appear in the list of "available permissions."

It appears that I accidentally migrated the model creation migrations to the default database before I correctly used the `--database DATABASE` flag with `manage.py migrate`. So I had the same table names in both the default and auxiliary databases. I dropped the tables in the default database, leaving only the tables in the auxiliary database, and then the tables appeared in the permissions list.